# Quitting Mac Terminal does not quit script run with sudo

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo, macos

I have a bash script called `testing` saved within `/usr/local/bin`.

In one Terminal window in macOS I run `sudo testing`. In a second terminal window, I generate a list of processes:

```
ps -axo tty,pid,ppid,args | { head -1; grep "bash\|testing" | grep -v grep; }
```

Which returns as expected:

```
TTY        PID  PPID ARGS
ttys000  73674 73673 -bash                              # login shell used to run sudo
ttys000  73701 73674 sudo testing                       # sudo process
ttys000  73702 73701 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/testing   # "testing" bash script being run by sudo
ttys001   3714  3713 -bash                              # second login shell used to generate this process list
```

However, after quitting the first Terminal window (**while** `testing` is still running within it), the process list looks like this:

```
TTY        PID  PPID ARGS
??       73701     1 sudo testing
??       73702 73701 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/testing
ttys001   3714  3713 -bash
```

As expected, the first login shell has been terminated and the second login shell is still running. But the sudo process and its forked (now-orphaned) child, the `testing` script, are still running!

I suspect this is because the user, not root, is the one closing the Terminal window, and as such does not have the necessary permissions to affect root processes. Is this correct? I feel like I'm missing something basic here. Is there some way to allow the root processes to be terminated when the Terminal window is closed?

Comment: I'm sure about one thing, root processes can't be killed by normal users. Executing a command using `sudo` is basically executing it as root user.

Comment: Maybe [apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) can help with `Terminal.app` questions? Maybe `Terminal.app` doesn't forward signals to its processes? A [Gnome Terminal](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal) does indeed terminate a (sudo) process when it's closed, except when explicitly called with e.g. `nohup`.